# Android: How to work with camera when activiy goes in background?

Tags: android, camera

How can I release the camera, when my activity goes into background? (For example by pressing the standby button on the phone)

```
    public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (cam != null) {
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
    rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout_background);
    cam = Camera.open();  
    cam.startPreview();
    p = cam.getParameters();
}
```

LogCat:

```
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe/spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.FlashLight}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2616)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2130)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:353)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:330)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at spicysoftware.spicytaschenlampe.FlashLight.onResume(FlashLight.java:182)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5280)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
02-20 11:46:40.040: E/AndroidRuntime(26439):    ... 12 more
```

THIS IS HOW ITS WORKING:

```
    public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    Log.v("OnPause", "True");
    if (cam != null) {
        Log.v("OnPause", "Cam isn't null");
        cam.stopPreview();
        Log.v("OnPause", "CamPreview stopped");
        cam.release();
        Log.v("OnPause", "CamReleased");
        cam = null;
        Log.v("OnPause", "Cam is null");
    }
}


@Override
protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 Log.v("OnResume", "True");
    if(cam != null){
        Log.v("OnResume", "Camera is in use");
    } else {
        Log.v("OnResume", "Camera isn't in use");
        rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout_background);
        cam = Camera.open();  
        Log.v("OnResume", "Camera has been opened");
        cam.startPreview();
        Log.v("OnResume", "CamPreview started");
        p = cam.getParameters();
        Log.v("OnResume", "Wrote parameters to variable p");
    }
}
```

Opening the camera in onResume does crash the app.

Best regards
MSeiz5

Answer (score 1):

Reopen and reset your camera in onResume.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();
 camera = Camera.open();

 // We resumed so lock the camera
 Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

 params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
 //params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
 //params.setWhiteBalance(Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);
 params.setJpegQuality(100);

 camera.setParameters(params);
 ImageView overlay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
 overlay.bringToFront();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. please check my onResume and logcat I added. it's crashing at cam = Camera.open(); and i don't know why...

Comment: Have you opened the camera somewhere else? If no, try restart your device. The connect error in native_setup usually occurs by unreleased camera.

Comment: And can you put a little bit more logs including those logs written by CameraService etc.

Comment: I found a way how to handle it! I post the working code at the question.

Comment: So actually you add an if-else to check if cam is null?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And now it works when I set the phone to standby mode.

Comment: And you don't have anything in onStart, onStop, onSurfaceCreated, onSurfaceDestroy?

Answer (score 0):

you are releasing it just fine but on resume it must be throwing the null pointer as camera object is null please reinitialize it before using it it will be just like you do onCreate.